# Simple Probablitiy question

Tags: probability

I am learning discrete probability distribution. I was going through this textbook question:

In a particular manufacturing plant, two machines (Aand B) produce a particular part. One machine (B) is
newer and faster. In one five-minute period, a lot consisting of 32 parts is produced. Twenty-two are produced
by machine B and the rest by machine A. Suppose an inspector randomly samples a dozen of the parts from
this lot.

a. What is the probability that exactly three parts were produced by machine A?

Solution: My Approach

a. P(A) = 10/32, P(B) = 22/32 and n = 12.

Using binomial distribution P(X=3) = 12C3*(10/32)^3*(22/32)^9 = 0.230370608

But the answer in textbook is 0.2644. Could please provide suggestion on why my approach is wrong how to get the right answer.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: Using the binomial distribution assumes $p[A]$ is constant. But the problem suggests sampling without replacement. (You should add the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find the probability of sampling 3 machine A parts out of 12, but machine A only made 10 parts in total.

If you think along those lines you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the probability of choosing 3 products of type A out of 12. There are 12 choose 3 different ways to do this, right?

Now what is the probability that the first product chosen has type A? 10/32 right?

Now what is the probability, given that the first one is type A, that the second one will also be type A? 9/31.

Ok so there is one tricksey part. You could do 10/32 * 9/31 * 8/30 * 22/29 * 21/28, ... all times 12 choose 3. But the denominators would be different for every different order of chosen products. What do we do about this?

Figure out this one trickey part and you have your solution.